# Patterns of simple as3 animations

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, animation, air

I want to add functionality to my photo gallery - different types of animation of the thumbs of the photos. Now I did like the code below. Everything works fine, but I desired to the thumbs bounced off the edges of the stage.

And most importantly, I need different patterns of animation - the movement as a 3D carousel, spinning in a circle, movement of the sun's rays and back, etc.

I would be very grateful if you have a ready-made pieces of code for these and similar animations.

```
[Bindable] private var stageW:int = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
[Bindable] private var stageH:int = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;

private var itemsVector:Vector.<Image>=new Vector.<Image>();
private var xSpeedVector:Vector.<Number>=new Vector.<Number>();
private var ySpeedVector:Vector.<Number>=new Vector.<Number>();

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

private function moveSetup():void {
for(var i:int = 0; i < FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.objects.length; i++){
    if (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.objects[i] is Image){
        var item:Image=FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.objects[i] as Image;
        item.x=Math.random()*stageW;
        item.y=Math.random()*stageH;
        var randomDirection:Number=Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
        this.addElement(item);
        itemsVector.push(item);
        xSpeedVector.push(2*Math.cos(randomDirection));
        ySpeedVector.push(2*Math.sin(randomDirection));
    }
}   
}

protected function update(event:Event):void {
    for(var i:uint=0;i<itemsVector.length;i++){
        itemsVector[i].x+=xSpeedVector[i];
        itemsVector[i].y+=ySpeedVector[i];
        if(itemsVector[i].x>stageW){
            itemsVector[i].x-=stageW;
        }
        if(itemsVector[i].x<0){
            itemsVector[i].x+=stageW;
        }
        if(itemsVector[i].y>stageH){
            itemsVector[i].y-=stageH;
        }
        if(itemsVector[i].y<0){
            itemsVector[i].y+=stageH;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157159)

Comment: ОК. "I desired to the thumbs bounced off the edges of the stage."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Greensock's TweenLite library](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) which is pretty much the standard for animation in Flash (and, as an added bonus, has recently been [ported to JavaScript](http://www.greensock.com/tag/javascript/)).

It supports various set easing functions including a bounce function. The paid version of the library even includes the ability to create custom easing functions. There's an interactive demo half-way down the first page I link to which allows you to play around with the library live and test the various easing functions.

A google search will turn up various tutorials explaining how to build (pseudo) 3D orbiting carousels, as well as third-party components which do the same. In fact, these are relatively simple to implement hinging, as they do, on a fairly simple bit of trigonometry. [This example](http://www.imajine.in/tutorials/flash/carousel.aspx) seems like it would make a reasonable starting point for you to adapt to suit your particular requirements.

3D effects can certainly be implemented in Flex. I would suggest you have a look at [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) which is an open-source 3D library written for the Flash platform. There's an example of a horizontal spiral effect implemented in Away3D (along with the complete source code) available [here](http://www.darklump.co.uk/blog/?p=246).

Comment: Thanks net.uk.sweet. I often use this library. I forgot to mention that the objects will be quite a lot (10-20), and an app for mobile devices. I think that too many resources will be spent. I'm looking for similar examples:http://www.guahanweb.com/2009/02/03/circular-rotation-and-orbiting-in-as3/

Comment: What's the problem with the example you link to?

Comment: No problem. On the contrary, I'm looking for simple examples of animation like as link.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://www.imajine.in/tutorials/flash/carousel.aspx

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the example. Only need to change a little. Now I have three animations. Another would be to find.

Comment: So is there another animation type you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe something with 3D effects. I am using flex and it is possible to connect these effects. The spiral motion, motion as the sun's rays, move on the path like waves. I'm doing something like vision board with photo of user in the center surrounded by photos of the desired items :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the results of this discussion. Hopefully given you enough to go on :)